# Putting everything on a (sub)path in the url

Tags: django, url

I want my entire Django project to be on a (sub)path `foo` on a domain.

`localhost:8000/foo/admin`, instead of `localhost:8000/admin`

`localhost:8000/foo/myapp/`, instead of `localhost:8000/myapp`

I see three parts:

1) Change the url dispatching. E.g. `/foo/admin,` should point to the correct views.

2) Correct links (to css, other pages, etc) in templates. E.g. the admin app's templates should point to `/foo/static/admin/css/base.css` instead of the usual `/static/admin/css/base.css`.

3) All static content must also be at `/foo`. e.g. the admin app's stylesheet should be at `/foo/static/admin/css/base.css` instead of the usual /static/admin/css/base.css.

Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: What you need to do depends a bit on what WSGI hosting mechanism you are using and you haven't stated that.

Comment: Does this line from httpd.conf answer that question? "PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On presumption of using mod_python, go read Django documentation about setting 'django.root' using SetEnv in Apache configuration file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/deployment/modpython/

With that set you should not need to add the mount point into patterns in urls.py.

You will still need to set STATIC_URL and MEDIA_URL to include the prefix as Daniel indicated.

Do note that mod_python is dead and support in Django deprecated and targeted for removal. If using Apache, you should consider moving to mod_wsgi instead.

Answer (score 2):

Just mount your WSGI app at `/foo` and set `STATIC_URL` and/or `MEDIA_URL` to `yourdomain.com/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following (*untested*) method:

1. In your top-level `urls.py` file have one pattern which looks like this:

   > `urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^foo/', include('main_urls.py'))`
2. And then have all of your normal patterns in `main_urls.py`. Everything in `main_urls.py` will be accessible under `/foo/`, rather than under `/`.